# How to delete a row in datatable if one of the columns value is not uniqe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms

In my datatable want to delete all rows where any column have a duplicate value or a non -uniqe value. For example: There are two columns in datatable, if column1 has duplicate value it should delete the whole row also in column2.

Want something like this:

```
 tblcsv = tblcsv.DefaultView.ToTable(true, column1.Trim(), column2.Trim());

for (int i = tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
               

                
                tblcsv.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim();
                tblcsv.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim();
               
                
                if (tblcsv.Rows[i][0] == DBNull.Value || tblcsv.Rows[i][1] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    tblcsv.Rows[i].Delete();
                }

                if (tblcsv.Rows[i][0] == string.Empty || tblcsv.Rows[i][1] == string.Empty)
                {
                    tblcsv.Rows[i].Delete();
                }

                if (tblcsv.Rows[i][0] != UniqueID || tblcsv.Rows[i][1] != UniqueID)
                {
                   tblcsv.Rows[i].Delete();
                }

               
                
            }
            tblcsv.AcceptChanges();
```

How to delete rows where any column value has duplicate values??

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you want to remove a row that has different columns that are equal with each-other or whether you want to delete rows which have some column values that match their corresponding columns in other rows?

Comment: I am talking about a column which has duplicate values for example Column1[house, dog, payment, house] I want to delete the first row with the house cause occured two times so that record should be deleted with the second column record!..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        DataView tblcsvFilter = tblcsv.DefaultView;

        foreach (DataRow dr in tblcsv.Rows)
        {
            if (dr[0].ToString() == "")
                dr.Delete();
            else if (dr[1].ToString() == "")
                dr.Delete();
            else if (GroupCount(tblcsvFilter, dr, dr.Table.Columns[0].ColumnName) > 1)
                dr.Delete();
            else if (GroupCount(tblcsvFilter, dr, dr.Table.Columns[1].ColumnName) > 1)
                dr.Delete();
        }
        tblcsv.AcceptChanges();


    int GroupCount(DataView rst, DataRow dr, string  sCol)
    {
        rst.RowFilter = $"{sCol} = '{dr[sCol]}'";            
        return rst.Count;
    }
```

Note that using .ToString() will convert a null to "".